# How can I determine the iOS version with iOS user-agent strings?

Tags: ios

I have a list of iOS User-Agent strings for approximately 50 different iPhone's and 30 different iPad's. I want to know if user-agent strings like Apple-iPad4C5/1202.410, Apple-iPhone4C1/1202.466 etc. can be used to determine the current iOS version running on these devices.

Answer (score 2):

My iPhone 6 running iOS 8.2 has this user agent string:
`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12D508 Safari/600.1.4`

You can see `iPhone OS 8_2` within that string. This is the OS version. You can parse that out.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has documented the format of the Safari User-Agent string in the [*Safari Web Content Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3). You can look at the examples there to see how the User-Agent embeds the iOS version number. Examples include `CPU iOS 2_0` and `CPU OS 3_2`.

Note, however, that third-party browsers (any app that uses a `UIWebView`, really, which includes many popular apps) can and often do customize the User-Agent.